# Favorite switch button in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-sharedpreferences

You might have seen in most of the apps, they use Add as favorite, and they will display user's favorite data to another Activity. I am trying to do but I am unable to do. I know for saving the value I must use Context.Mode_append in shared Preferences, but which value?

Do I send position of recyclerView list items or I need to send string? I have found similar question in Stack Overflow but none of these are helpful because they aren't on detail. Below is the screenshot and I am also trying that if the start button is press then color this in yellow, below is the code I tried but it only changes when I hold the button.

start.xml from drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" android:state_pressed="true" />

<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_on" android:state_selected="true" />
<item android:drawable="@android:drawable/star_big_off" />
</selector>
```

I called button in cardView where CardView is my parent layout

```
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/star"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Where is your code that sets a click listener on the drawable? Favoriting is no different than a button click event

Comment: I haven't called button for a click listener yet. In fact I add this in cardview.  see my updated question 
       <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/star"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            />

Comment: Please [edit] your post. Comments are not meant for code. And you set a XML drawable, okay, that has no "favoriting" logic behind it.

Comment: sorry, I mistakenly hit enter. Please see my edited question. I have done that

Comment: Thanks. And again, I ask, what have you tried to set a OnClickListener onto the ImageButton of the ViewHolder of the RecyclerView adapter?

Comment: I haven't code that yet but I am planning to code that if the user click on ImageButton then change this start  icon to yellow colored and then save the selected row as  per position or string, as you will guide,  It must use sharedprefrences because later when users back the button clicked item must be in yellow and I will display the selected pressed button row in favourites Activity. How to do like that? I have many googled about it but none of those worked. Many many thanks cricket_007

Comment: You say "none of those worked", but what are "those"? You should include what you tried in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Add an `OnClickListener` to the *star ImageButton*, first give it an id and they define it inside your class. You didn't give much knowledge about how you saving or retrieving the data but for the info, you given adding an `OnClickListener` is the best solution.